# Usually when we get "org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory" error?

Tags: java, dwr

While deploying a dwr web app, i'm continuously getting this error.
I dont know why this coming. I cant run any of my DWR sample projects.

Apart from that, for what we get this ClassNotFound Error. What the concept here?

This is starting of long list of error, iam getting.

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet dwr-invoker
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
```

Anyone tell me how to fix this problem.. or tell me what are possible situations that may cause this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't have Commons Logging available in your servlet container. DWR [relies on this](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/server/servlet/logging.html). You should probably deploy this as a library within your web app. It's simply a logging library that delegates to other available logging libraries/frameworks (Log4j, Java logging etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to download [Apache Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/) and add it to your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the commons-logging.jar to the classpath.